# fstream vs. iostream and mkfifo

Tags: c++, fstream, fifo

I have a *client* and a *server* which communicate via stdin/stdout. This works fine:

    `mkfifo fifo0
    client < fifo0 | server > fifo0`

Both *client* and *server* are basically this:

```
int main() {
  run(cin, cout);
  return 0;
}
```

Now I want to debug the server. So in 2 different shells I want to do this:

    `gdb --args server fifo1 fifo0`

and this:

    `client fifo0 fifo1`

I alter `main` to take filename arguments. Unfortunately, the server stalls. Using **gdb**, I see that it stalls in the `ifstream` constructor, here:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char const fin[] = "fifo1";
  cerr << "in: '" << fin << "'\n";
  ifstream sin(fin);
  cerr << "opened\n";
  char const fout[] = "fifo0";
  cerr << "out: '" << fout << "'\n";
  ofstream sout(fout, ofstream::out | ofstream::app);
  cerr << "opened\n";
  run(sin, sout);
  return 0;
}
```

Why is the behavior different when the output stream is `ofstream("fifo0")`? Any solutions?

---

## Solved, but why?

It works now that I open the output fifo before the input fifo, like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char const fout[] = "fifo0";
  cerr << "out: '" << fout << "'\n";
  ofstream sout(fout, ofstream::out | ofstream::app);
  cerr << "opened\n";

  char const fin[] = "fifo1";
  cerr << "in: '" << fin << "'\n";
  ifstream sin(fin);
  cerr << "opened\n";
  run(sin, sout);
  return 0;
}
```

Would anyone please explain why that solved the problem?

Comment: Are you running them together?

Comment: I'm not entirely following what you are doing but I suspect you are just running into the normal FIFO semantics, namely the opens will block until there is a reader/writer on the other side.  Since the shell redirects them for you it wasn't noticeable until you did it on your own.

Comment: I've simplified the question down to what I'm sure of. Is this simpler question more clear? @littleadv: Yes, simultaneously in 2 different terminals.

Answer (score 0):

@Duck: You're right. Opening the FIFO blocks until there is something on *each side*. The shell normally takes care of that detail when using redirection (`| < >`).

Answer (score 0):

Since you may be using Linux, this comes from the fifo man page:
"Under Linux, opening a FIFO for read and write will succeed both in blocking and nonblocking mode.  POSIX leaves this behavior undefined.  This can be used to open a FIFO for writing while there are no readers available."